# UITableView changes content size

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a table view in which I am showing N images initially, and as the users scrolls down, it loads N more images when the bottom is reached. Now when the user touches one of these images, I open another view using a modal segue and when the user returns, the table remains at the touched cell ( this is when one of the images is in the first N loaded images). But when the user touches any of the subsequently loaded ones, the table size reverts back to the original size (when the first N images were loaded.)

This happens only to the table size and not to the NSMutableArray I use for the table's data. I have used the following statements, and even then this happens:

```
// in viewDidLoad

[self.flowTable setDataSource:self];
[self.flowTable setDelegate:self];


// whenever new images are loaded

[self.flowTable reloadData];
```

When I tried to check at exactly which point this happens, I found that the content size doesn't change until after the segue is called. And by the time the "viewDidAppear" method is called, the content size of the table is reduced. Any idea why this might be happening?

**EDIT**

Well I load lazily from the internet, and whenever I load more data, The code looks something like this:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
   // connection finishes loading and the data is prepared to be updated

     NSDictionary *flowArr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:0 error:nil];


    [self storeImageData: flowArr];

    [self.flowTable reloadData];


}


- (void) storeImageData:(NSMutableArray *)arr
{
     for(NSDictionary* data in arr)
    {

        // image data is stored as convenient and the NSMutableArray is updated as such

        [self.imageData addObject: det];

    }


}
```

Comment: What data structures are you using? It'd help to know how you're structuring the datasource of the table view.

Comment: @Zaph, Yes, the count of the NSMutableArray that I use doesn't change. Only the table view size does.

Comment: @GuyKogus, I'm using a NSMutableArray to set the contents of the cells.

Comment: have you tried to add `[self.flowTable reloadData]` to your `viewDidAppear`, also, are you enabling AutoResize ?

Comment: Adding reloadData to viewDidAppear helped. But I hadn't enabled autoresize. I will try it now. :)

Answer (score 5):

I can't see anything out of the ordinary that you're doing here. The table view's content size is based on the number of rows in each section times the height of each cell. So long as these numbers are correct, you'll get the right content size.

If you really want to know exactly when the content size changes, you can add key-value observation to the table view's content size, using something like:

```
[tableView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:0 context:NULL];
```

You can then breakpoint `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` to see exactly when the change is occurring.

Comment: Hmm. I am programmatically calling the segue. And the ViewDidAppear method is getting called the after the prepareforsegue method. The content size changes even before either the observer or the viewdiddisappear methods are called.

Comment: KVO worked but I still can't see where the change is occurring.

Comment: Add a breakpoint in the `observeValueForKeyPath...` method, it may give you a hint as to where it's happening.

Comment: contentSize changed when `reloadData` called, but I do not know why while   the data source do not change